# Yeoman angular generator error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

When I'm using the angular yeoman generator, I'm getting the following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module './lib/pack.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-karma\node_modules\yeoman-generator\n
ode_modules\download\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\decompress-tarbz2\node_modules\tar\tar.js:171:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Any idea why?
npm version 1.4.28
node version 0.10.33
yeoman version 1.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Try remove your `generator-karma` and `generator-angular`, run `npm cache clean`, and install them again

Comment: how do you remove a generator?

Comment: generators are just npm packages. remove them like the other packages. e.g. `npm uninstall -g generator-karma`

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue, this might not be the solution but your version of npm is out of date, try typing:

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

As referenced [On the npm website](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node) (note they use sudo in the example but it might not be necessary). after that:

```
npm --version
```

Is currently 2.1.12 so it should be higher than that.

You can then try:

```
npm update
```

to upgrade everything to the latest version ([See this page](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-local-packages)).

This may solve the problem.